# Run a bat file from javascript

Tags: javascript, batch-file, jscript, wsh

I'm trying to run a bat file using javascript. I've tried using powershell but it didn't seem to work properly. Here is the code I tried:

```
var oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
oShell.Exec("D:");
oShell.Exec("cd dir");
oShell.Exec("start user.bat");
```

I've also tried that:

```
var oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
oShell.Exec("start D:\dir\user.bat");
```

Sometimes it runs, sometimes I get those errors "Expected hexadecimal digit", "Access is denied".
I'm really confused. All I'm trying to do is execute a bat file from a javascript file.

Anyone has any idea how to do it? Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, JavaScript doesn't have any operating system services. So you are really referring to a Windows Script Host (WSH) script that happens to be written in JavaScript.

Second, `start` is not an executable but rather a command that is built into `cmd.exe`.

With the confusion out of the way, it sounds like you want to execute a shell script (batch file) from a WSH script. The simplest way is like this (this is somewhat close to what you tried already):

```
var wshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
wshShell.Run("D:\\dir\\user.bat");
```

To create the `WshShell` COM object reference (progid `WScript.Shell`), use the `new` keyword and the `ActiveXObject` constructor. Also, you need to double your backslashes (`\`) in JavaScript strings because `\` escapes characters in JavaScript strings.

Comment: Thank you! At the beginning I had the feeling it might be something with the slashes but it didn't help so I thought it's not it. But I guess the problem was both that and the "start" command! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Bill_Stewart this works like a charm. But, it requires "Initialize and script ActiveX controls not marked as safe for scripting" to enable. sometimes this action asks for accept or reject. Is there any way, which will say that on every system whenever this Shell script will run, will ask for this warning?

Comment: How are you running the script? (My answer refers only to script executed by cscript/wscript/mshta, not JavaScript executed in other contexts such as browsers.)

Comment: @@Bill_Stewart ...hi sir..can you tell me one thing....that...how can i receive a string from exe back to the javascript...is it Possible...? if yes...then how can i achieve this..thank u..

Answer (score 1):

Also, check the following version it might help;

```
var runnableScript = exec('path_to.bat',
    (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        console.log(stdout);
        console.log(stderr);
        if (error !== null) {
            console.log(`exec error: ${error}`);
        }
    });
```

Comment: @paddotk Be sure to include `child_process` module

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html