# I need to create a Bookmarklet to run a batchfile

Tags: javascript, powershell, batch-file

I need help on writing code to create a bookmarklet in firefox and chrome.

After clicking on bookmarklet it has to run a batch file/powershell file pointed to it.

i wrote a code as below:

```
javascript:(function(){var wshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell"); 
wshShell.Run("F:\App\bin\CCC.bat")})();
```

but it throws an error as below:

> ActiveXObject` is not defined

Comment: Might this helps? [Run a bat file from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42985964/run-a-bat-file-from-javascript)

Comment: This article says .. we cannot use that from browser bookmark let

Comment: Please help on how to allow ActiveXObject via browser.

Comment: Go this Page : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605946/how-to-enable-activex-in-chrome)